# why self.view.layer.contentScale = 1 in retina device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The document said "For layers attached to a view, the view changes the scale factor automatically to a value that is appropriate for the current screen."    Im confused! why not 2 or 3 for retina device?

Comment: is your view in the view-hierarchy and visible when you try to read the value? did you create the layer manually?

Comment: Check out  your answer here ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459078/when-do-i-need-to-set-the-contentsscale-property-of-a-calayer

Comment: @holex it is the original layer